# Trying to update the content of language copy in AEM

Tags: aem

I was having a website with en and having pages under it.Now i created another language copy named French (fr).I have made some changes in my English copy,how can i update the same changes from one language copy to other.

Comment: What kind of content did you modify? Is it relevant to both language copies or do you need the update to be connected with a translation? Perhaps this content could be defined in a single place and just included by both language copies for ease of management?

Answer (score 0):

@Shivani

Making a language copy just copies the content from source(en) to the new language(fr). If you want changes in en page to reflect in the copied pages fr pages automatically, you will have to create fr pages as **live copy** of source(en) page and specify appropriate rollout configs while creating a live copy.

Of course, if it's a text in english that is modified at source, this will not automatically translate to french text. Live copy will copy the modified english text to the french page, content reauthoring in specific language is required. But for images and assets in general, live copy will work out.

You can refer [this](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/multi_site_manager.html#Creating%20Blueprints%20and%20Live%20Copies) for more info.